# Prometheus with SpringBoot

Tags: spring-boot, prometheus, spring-boot-actuator

I have one big question about working with Prometheus and SpringBoot. I know about that I can connect Java Application (SpringBoot) and Prometheus as dependency --> then I can monitor that application. I really want to know, is there any way, to create that application and monitor other applications? I mean, I am wondering about connecting my application (SpringBoot with Prometheus) with Eureka Server (it is connected with many microServices I want to monitor), get the metrics from other microservices, and send it to grafana for creating dashboards.

Comment: So you want to integrate Prometheus in a Spring Boot application. Why?

Answer (score 1):

unless your enviroment is Kubernetes native, working with prometheus is pain in non kubernetes env. In a spring world, spring gateway itselff has servicemesh which takes care of the metrics and telemetry. you can use either EFK or ELK for your concern. F=fluentd. in EFK. or your can use managed environment like New Relic for the same but in that case you have to pay them.